# accessing Kafka metadata with Python KafkaConsumer

Tags: python, metadata, kafka-consumer-api

I have a simple Kafka reader class.  I really don't remember where I got this code.  Could have found it, or my previous self may have created it from various examples.  Either way, it allows me to quickly read a kafka topic.

```
class KafkaStreamReader():
def __init__(self, schema_name, topic, server_list):
    self.schema = get_schema(schema_name)
    self.topic = topic
    self.server_list = server_list
    self.consumer =  KafkaConsumer(topic, bootstrap_servers=server_list,
                                   auto_offset_reset = 'latest',
                                   security_protocol="PLAINTEXT")


def decode(self, msg, schema):
    parsed_schema = avro.schema.parse(schema)
    bytes_reader = io.BytesIO(msg)
    decoder = avro.io.BinaryDecoder(bytes_reader)
    reader = avro.io.DatumReader(parsed_schema)
    record = reader.read(decoder)
    return record

def fetch_msg(self):
    event = next(self.consumer).value
    record = self.decode(event, self.schema)
    return record
```

To use it, I instantiate an object and loop forever reading data such as this:

```
consumer = KafkaStreamReader(schema, topic,  server_list)
while True:
    message = consumer.fetch_msg()
    print message
```

I'm sure there are better solutions, but this works for me.

What I want to get out of this, is the meta data on the Kafka record.  A coworker in another group used Java or Node and was able to see the following information on the record.

```
{ 
  topic: 'clickstream-v2.origin.test',
  value:      
  {
    schema:payload_data/jsonschema/1-0-3',
    data: [ [Object] ] },
    offset: 16,
    partition: 0,
    highWaterOffset: 17,
    key: null,
    timestamp: 2018-07-25T17:01:36.959Z 
  }
}
```

I want to access the timestamp field using the Python KafkaConsumer.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution.  If I change the fetch_msg method I can figure out how to access it.

```
def fetch_msg(self):
    event = next(self.consumer)
    timestamp = event.timestamp
    record = self.decode(event.value, self.schema)
    return record, timestamp
```

Not the most elegant solution as I personally don't like methods that return multiple values.  However, it illustrates how to access the event data that I was after.  I can work on more elegant solutions